# lastlogin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 minute) in PHP?

Tags: php, date

This is my SQL statement, however I want to rewrite it to simple PHP, as I've already pulled out the lastlogin in to a variable, so how do I do it?

```
lastlogin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 minute)
```

Let me try to reexplain perhaps... I have a if statement, I have a time saved in my database in format (0000-00-00 00:00:00) In order to the if statement to be executed, The time in database + 15 minutes must have passed :) And I don't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

you can't rewrite it in PHP as it's obviously used to filter your data and should be used as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strtotime($lastlogin) > (time()+15*60))
```

Comment: It didn't work! if (strtotime($lastlogin) > (time()+15*60)) { even though the time is less then 15 minutes, the statement is true lastlogin format is 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: If my time saved (0000-00-00 00:00:00) which I make to Unix timestamp have been therefor 15 minutes, How should I do? Since, I can't get it to work properly.

Comment: @John123: $lastlogin should be 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Let me try to reexplain perhaps... I have a if statement, I have a time saved in my database in format (0000-00-00 00:00:00) In order to the if statement to be executed, The time in database + 15 minutes must have passed :) And I don't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you converted lastlogin to a unix timestamp:

```
if ($lastlogin > (time()+15*60))
```